# Ajax Infinite Scroll works on Desktop but not on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't get this ajax infinite scroll to work on a touchscreen or mobile cell phone.

I have been trying to calculate the screen size with header, content and footer divs, but nothing works.

How can I trigger a function when I am at the bottom of the page?

Found som examples here, but none of them works.

This is what I have right now, working on a desktop.

Thanks,

```
<script>
        
$(window).scroll(function() {
            
if($(window).scrollTop() +  $(window).height() >=$(document).height()) {

var last_id = $(".trailerid:last").attr("id");
                loadMore(last_id);
            }
        });

        function loadMore(last_id){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'loadMore.inc.php?lastTrailerId=' + last_id,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $("#trailerData").append(data);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert('Servern svarar inte...');
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#the_root__element_and_root_margin). This API is designed to detect whenever certain *observed* elements come in (and out) of the viewport. It's a more performant alternative than listening to the scroll event.

With the API you could place an element at the bottom of the page, let's call this element the *trigger*. Whenever this trigger comes into view, call the `loadMore` function and add items to the list. The trigger should now be pushed to the bottom and out of view again. Scroll down to repeat this process.

I've made a demo below which uses this technique to simulate an *infite scroll* effect. It works the same way as described above.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');

const loadMore = () => {
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.className = 'item';
  list.append(item);
}

const handleIntersect = entries => {
  for (const { isIntersecting } of entries) {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      loadMore();
    }
  }
};

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  treshold: 0
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
observer.observe(trigger);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, black);
}

.item::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item);
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="trigger"></div>
```